# CMake in CLion, invoke remote build instead of building localy

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I want to achieve following, I have a cmake configuration in CLion, include paths, source files and executable. The source cannot be built locally, so I have to invoke remote build, for example using SSH. The question is how do I invoke Build command, but I dont have `add_executable`, so nothing built locally? I tried to add `add_custom_command` and remove the `add_executable`. However it didnt make the trick.

 Short version of my CMakeList.txt
'

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(boo)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
include_directories(lib/include lib/include/control lib/include/ext lib/include/infra lib/include/boo)
file(GLOB_RECURSE BOO_FILES
        "*.h"
        "*.cpp"
        "*.thrift"
        "*.json"
        )

add_executable(boo ${BOO_FILES})

add_custom_command(TARGET boo PRE_BUILD COMMAND "some command here")
```

I think it is about `add_custom_target` but I cant figure out how to put all of it together

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out
just leave the `add_executable` as is and add additional targets to build
Something like

```
# just run my remote make
add_custom_command(OUTPUT BooMake COMMAND your remote make command goes here WORKING_DIRECTORY "c:/Program Files/PuTTY/")
add_custom_target(BooBuild ALL DEPENDS BooMake)
```

Additional configuration `BooBuild` will appear in CLion, just run it
Limitation, error messages are not clickable, gotta figure it out